# Apply Style to Polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles, polygon

I want to apply the following `Style` to my `Polygon`:

```
<Style xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   TargetType="{x:Type Polygon}">

<Style.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="Shape.IsMouseOver" Value="True">

        <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush>#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness">
            <Setter.Value>
                <s:Double>2</s:Double>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="Shape.IsMouseOver" Value="False">

        <Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness">
            <Setter.Value>
                <s:Double>0</s:Double>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Trigger>

</Style.Triggers>


<Setter Property="Shape.Fill" Value="{x:Null}"/>  

</Style>
```

When the cursor is over my Polygon I want a Black stroke, when the cursor is not over my Polygon I don't want to see anything. Why this style does not work (I do not see anything)?

### Edit:

This is my Polygon:

```
var pol = new Polygon();

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("myStyle.xaml", FileMode.Open))
       pol.Style = XamlReader.Load(stream) as Style;
```

Comment: Can you post a sample polygon?

Comment: @nemesv I add the code that I use to create the Polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the `Shape.Fill` to `Null`, try this instead:

```
<Setter Property="Shape.Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
```